# Hive doesn't read latest HDFS file data until I close OutputStream

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I use Spark Streaming to append data to HDFS file. For each batch, I write data and then call hsync to make sure data is persistent.

When execute hadoop fs -cat command, I can see my update is persistent, however if I execute select count(*) from table in Hive, the total count will not change until I close the OutputStream.

Also I noticed, when execute hadoop fs -ls command, HDFS file last modification time and file size will not change until close the OutputStream.

How it happens? Is there a way to let Hive read new data but don't close OutputStream?

Edited@20180811

I guess the problem is, before file closed, the file size is not sync to namenode. when MR job launched, it get the file size from namenode which is not the actual size, and tell MR job the read the size, so the new appended data are not read.
Is there config properties to avoid this?

Comment: `count(*)` alone is not reliable -- it's crazy, but someone decided that HQL might deliver wrong results based on stale statistics and whatnot. Try sthg more elaborate that forces Hive to run a proper Yarn job, like `... where A is not null` if you know for sure that A cannot be null (but Hive doesn't)

Comment: AFAIK the HDFS NameNode does not update file metadata until the DataNode-in-charge-of-writes signals that *(a)* the client closed the connection or *(b)* the current block is complete _[because it reached the limit, or the client forced a reset]_ or *(c)* the client connection timed-out after 60 min.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter thanks for your replay. I tried your suggestion, but not works either. And I think MR job is run because hive console report MR progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is when init MR job, client will get file length from name node and calculate file split. When file is not close, file length is not sync to name node, so client don't know there is new data. I customize file input format to verify this problem, @  https://github.com/yantzu/hendeavour